# Is it possible to change from Student Visa to Work Visa in Germany in order to work full time during studies?

Tags: germany, working-visas

I am from an European country outside the EU/EEA and I am staying in Germany on a Student Residency Permit as a Master student. I got an offer for a full-time position job in my field of study (software development), and considering that my study is a part-time program I would theoretically be able to work full-time while still finishing my degree.

My question is: would I be able to get a work visa so that I can work full-time while studying?

Comment: I'll close this as a duplicate, but do let us know that really answers your question. I think it does as I do believe there is no restriction on taking up studies while on a work permit - as long as you are fulfilling the conditions of the work permit.

Comment: Thank you, that helps. The only difference is that I don't plan to interrupt my studies, but I guess that shouldn't change the answer.